# Failed to build Swift framework test

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing, frameworks

I'm trying to run my test for a custom framework but I get this error:

> "xctest[75653:2358339] The bundle “Tests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle."

I added some dependencies using carthage to the framework. Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

- Copy the xcodeprojs from your dependencies inside your workspace
- In the buildPhase/link binary with libraries from the test target, add the dependencies clicking + and choosing them from the workspace (you must have your cocoa framework there + the dependencies)
- Command B
- Command U

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Just set manually your **Host Application** in the test target

[image]